# convert standard timestampt to epoch format using awk/nawk on Solaris

Tags: awk, timestamp, solaris, epoch, nawk

I need to convert some timestamp on Solaris to epoch format without any GNU installed.

I gave it a try with below code. However, sometime the return value has 1-2 days deviated from the correct value

```
echo "Mar 20 20:09" | nawk -v FS="[: ]+" 'BEGIN {
    month_array["Jan"]="01";
    month_array["Feb"]="02";
    month_array["Mar"]="03";
    month_array["Apr"]="04";
    month_array["May"]="05";
    month_array["Jun"]="06";
    month_array["Jul"]="07";
    month_array["Aug"]="08";
    month_array["Sep"]="09";
    month_array["Oct"]="10";
    month_array["Nov"]="11";
    month_array["Dec"]="12";
}
{
    year=2016;
    month=month_array[$1];
    day=$2; hour=$3; minute=$4;
    if (month > 2) {
        month=month+1;
    } else {
        month=month+13; year=year-1;
    }

    day=(year*365)+(year/4)-(year/100)+(year/400)+(month*306001/10000)+day;
    days_since_epoch=day-719591;
    seconds_since_epoch=(days_since_epoch*86400)+(hour*3600)+(minute*60);
    printf "%d\n", seconds_since_epoch;
}'
1458677340

bash-3.2$ ctime 1458677340
Tue Mar 22 20:09:00 2016
```

Thanks so much

Comment: what is this magic number? `719591`

Comment: it stands for "Jan 1 1970". Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Midnight GMT on that date is epoch time `0`

Comment: @glennjackman That's the number of days between "Jan 1 0000" and Jan 1 1970.

Comment: If you want, you can translate this code into awk: [$time_utils:from_ctime](https://neil.fraser.name/scripts/moowebbrowser.py?db=LambdaCore.db&obj=43&verbnum=5)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all month have 30.6 days is obviously doomed.

Here are two ways to do what you want to achieve under Solaris.

Using `touch` and `truss` (for the fun):

```
$ touch -t "03202009" file
$ truss -f -v 'lstat,lstat64' ls -d file 2>&1 | nawk '/mt =/ {printf "%d\n",$10}'
1458504540
$ ctime 1458504540
2016/03/20, 20:09:00
```

Using `perl`:

```
$ touch -t "03202009" file
$ perl -sle '@stat=stat($filename); print "$stat[8]"' -- -filename=file
1458504540
```

Comment: Thanks jlliagre, your solution works great. I'm curious is it possible to "calculate" the timestamp using nawk?

Comment: It is of course possible but tedious. The code might be relatively simple if you limit the range of dates accepted as input.